# Exchange 2010: Retrieve mailboxes updated after a certain time

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I would like to get all mailboxes modified after certain date and time. When I do

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity SomeMailbox | Get-Member
```

I see only 4 attributes which are of type Date. LastExchangeChangedTime, WhenChanged, WhenChangedUTC, WhenCreated, WhenCreatedUTC.

Out of these LastExchangeChangedTime is always blank. Not sure for what it is used.

The WhenChanged, WhenChangedUTC attributes looks useful but they change even when someone updates pure AD attribute like 'Password Never Expires'..!!. If I get mailboxes based on this, I would be getting mailboxes whose mailbox attributes may not be updated at all! This is incorrect.

My questions are:

1. what is the correct mailbox attribute based on which I can get list
   of mailboxes whose exchange only attributes are updated after a
   certain time?
2. Does exchange provide any changelog kind of thing -
   like LDAP directory does?

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: By mailbox updated, do you mean last time email was received/delete/sent? If so, this is not a property you can pull out of LDAP or any cmdlets.

Comment: Thanks Raf for your reply. When I say updated, I mean updates to any of the exchange related attribute of the mailbox like Alias, PrimarySMTPAddress, Display Name etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no attribute you can use which increments *only* when Exchange attributes change.